# How can I extract date (of any format) from text?

Tags: python, date, datefinder

Suppose I have text like `Based on 1. And it is 15-May-2016`. I have to find the date from the text which can be of any format. I was tring with

```
list( datefinder.find_dates( text, strict = False))
```

The problem is this function imputing 1. as 2021, 4, 1 if I set `strict = False` and if I set `strict =True` then it is not detecting 15-May-2016.

Is there any other way to find any format of dates from text?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the dates you are interested in always will be more then 7 characters, then you can do:

```
>>> import datefinder
>>> text = "Based on 1. And it is 15-May-2016."
>>> for dt, idx in datefinder.find_dates( text, strict=False, index=True):
...     if idx[1] - idx[0] > 7:
...         print(dt, text[idx[0]: idx[1]])
2016-05-15 00:00:00  15-May-2016.
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. The character length is not known. So if the text contains `15-May` that should also be considered as date. But 15-May and 1. would have same character length in this case.